# What is the best way to enable TFS users their own kanban board

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, kanban

Is it really possible to for TFS users to create "personal" kanban boards. We have users that are in a shared service group so that they maybe getting work from multiple teams. Is there a way that they can create a person Kanban view to they can manage all their work?

Answer (score 0):

You'd create a Team and then add this one person to the team. Configure an Area which is specific for this user. Any work assigned to this Area will show up on this Team's backlog.

Comment: Or, with a central backlog, use the view option that breaks the board down by user.

Comment: Creating a 1 user Team, could work, but once I do that then everyone will want one, and I don't want to support that. We are talking potentially hundreds.

Comment: If each person would need to be able to setup their own workflow, then Team is currently the only way to go. Kanban board configurations are linked to teams. if the workflow is the same for all, then using the filters may work.

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to automate a team for everyone.